# PHP check if IPAddress is local

Tags: php, networking, ip

Can i check if an ip is in a private network?

```
<?php
function isLocalIPAddress($IPAddress)
{
    return ( !filter_var($IPAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE ) );
}

var_dump( isLocalIPAddress('127.0.0.1') ); // false
var_dump( isLocalIPAddress('192.168.1.20') ); // true
var_dump( isLocalIPAddress('64.233.160.0') ); // false
```

Why is `isLocalIPAddress('127.0.0.1')` giving `false` instead of `true`?

Isn't 127.0.0.1 a private ip?

---

**UPDATE**

Solution I used:

```
<?php
function isLocalIPAddress($IPAddress)
{
    if( strpos($IPAddress, '127.0.') === 0 )
        return true;

    return ( !filter_var($IPAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE ) );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a [test run](http://3v4l.org/GphhY), we can see that output for PHP 5.2.0 → 5.3.5 is `false`, while output for PHP 5.3.6 → 7.0.0beta1 and  hhvm-3.3.1 → 3.8.0 is `true`.

To solve your problem you can check for php version and if it is in the first range add:

```
function isLocalIPAddress($IPAddress)
{
    if($IPAddress == '127.0.0.1'){return true;} <-- add this
    return ( !filter_var($IPAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE ) );
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the solution that I would use.

Comment: @ar099968 - that should do it, glad I helped

Answer (score 2):

```
filter_var($addr, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE);
```

This is my production flags. Private IP classes and loopback interfaces are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php 127.0.0.1 is not included in either FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE or FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE.

Edit:

There is also a comment there on how to deal with loopback.

Comment: the comment you are addressing is 3 years old and 127.0.0.1 was added with later php versions

Comment: Yes, however there is a chance he is using older version of PHP since it does not work for him.

Comment: yes there might be, but your answer is not addressing that. you need to mention both cases :)